# Laravel - Combine {!! ... !!} and asset('image/my.png') result the asset code print not show image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

As the title said, I try to show HTML code using `{!! ... !!}`, HTML code comes from Database. But when the code has an `asset('image/my.png')`, it does not show the image, otherwise, it shows the code `asset('image/my.png')`.

How to show image using :

```
asset('image/my.png')
```

The code :

```
<div>
<img src="{{ asset('images/my1.png') }}
{!! <img src="{{ asset('images/my2.png') }}" /> !!}
</div>
```

But need to append HTML code from Database between my blade View?

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Comment: I have add the code. Please recheck. thank you.

Comment: A " quote is missing from your code

Comment: Sorry wrong copy paste. But the real code has " at the end of line. Please recheck. thank you.

Comment: SO, you are getting `<img src="{{ asset('images/my2.png') }}" />` from database?

Comment: in `{!!  !!}` block you can use **raw HTML** so it won't be processed by blade

Comment: Yes, blade not working for me inside {!! ... !!}

Comment: Just use string concatenation like this `{!! '<img src="'.asset(' asset("images/my2.png")').'">' !!}`

Comment: I think concat for complex code will hard to do. Any other solution? How about using simple path without using asset ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

`{!! !!}` will output the raw string provided so will not evaluate blade templates. What you can instead do is something like:

```
  //Just to know what we're talking about
  $databaseString = "<img src=\"{{ asset('images/my2.png') }}\" />"; 
  $compiled = Blade::compileString($databaseString);
  // $compiled = <img src="<?php echo e(asset('images/my2.png')); ?>" />
```

and to display it you can use:

```
  <div>
      {!! eval("?>".$compiled) !!}
  </div>
```

Of course this comes with the usual caveat of **never use this to run untrusted code**

Comment: Blade is undefined. Can you explain which import do you do?

Comment: @Crocodile It needs `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<div>
     <img src="{{ asset('images/my1.png') }}
     $myDatabase = "<img src="{{ asset('images/my2.png') }}" />";
     {{html_entity_decode($myDatabase);}}
</div>
```

Comment: it show <img src> code / HTML as text not compiled the HTML and PHP ?